# EF Dynamic Projection failing Tests with Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I am writing unit tests for my service which talks to the database using Entity Framework as ORM. In my service, there is a piece of code that dynamically projects  against a table to select an anonymous type object like shown below -

```
string selectQuery = "new ( " + string.Join(",", someColumns) + ")";
var values = await context.MyTable.Where(data => data.Id == someId).Select(selectQuery).ToListAsync();
```

This is so because the columns I am projecting are not known at compile time and can vary on certain conditions. The production code works as expected using the code above.

However, it starts throwing `System.ArgumentException` with the following message when I run my test -

> Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DynamicClass1]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyTable]'

Shared below is my test -

```
var values = new List<MyTable>
        {
            new MyTable
            {
                Id = 1,
                Column1 = value1,
                Column2 = value2,
                Column3 = value3,
                Column4 = value4
            },
            new MyTable
            {
                Id = 2,
                Column1 = value5,
                Column2 = value6,
                Column3 = value7,
                Column4 = value8             
            }
        }.AsQueryable();


var mockValues = new Mock<DbSet<MyTable>>();

mockValues.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>>()
            .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(values.GetEnumerator()));

        mockValues.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(values.Provider));
        mockValues.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(values.Expression);
        mockValues.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(values.ElementType);
        mockValues.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(values.GetEnumerator());

Mock<Context> contextMock = new Mock<Context>();
contextMock.Setup(x => x.MyTable).Returns(mockValues.Object);

var result = await _myService.SomeMethod(contextMock.Object, ...);
Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

I have referred the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking#async) for `async` support for my test.

By looking at the exception, I guessed this should be something related to the dynamic projection that I am using here so I changed the code in the service to below -

```
var values = await context.MyTable.Where(data => data.Id == someId).Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Column1, x.Column2, x.Column4 }).ToListAsync();
```

which basically removes the dynamic construct and as I had expected, it worked.

So, the question is - Is there a way to have columns projected dynamically and still have my tests work.

Comment: In your test code, what is `T` (seen in `.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>>()` and other places)?

Comment: Yes - do not mock ORM, test database related implementation details against real database or "In-Memory" database.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - The code around `T` is basically a generic method which I call for setting up the mocks for different tables. So, in this case it refers to `MyTable` here...